# Pandas str.split without stripping split pattern

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Example code:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: serie = pd.Series(['this#is#a#test', 'another#test'])

In [3]: serie.str.split('#', expand=True)
Out[3]:
         0     1     2     3
0     this    is     a  test
1  another  test  None  None
```

Is it possible to split without stripping the split criteria string? Output of the above would be:

```
Out[3]:
         0     1     2     3
0     this   #is    #a #test
1  another #test  None  None
```

**EDIT 1**: Real use case would be to keep matching pattern, for instance:

```
serie.str.split(r'\n\*\*\* [A-Z]+', expand=True)
```

And [A-Z]+ are processing steps in my case, which i want to keep for further processing.

Comment: Probably best to use a regex then.

Comment: Putting the [A-Z] in a capture group () should let you back referemce them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could split by using a positive look ahead. So the split point will be the point just before the postivie look ahead expression.

```
import pandas as pd

serie = pd.Series(['this#is#a#test', 'another#test'])
print(serie.str.split('(?=#)', expand=True))
```

OUTPUT

```
         0      1     2      3
0     this    #is    #a  #test
1  another  #test  None   None
```

Comment: what python version are you using

Comment: Interesting I have run this in 3.7.0

Comment: No worries, i will deep dive this. :) Thanks

Comment: i will have a look too as its got me curious.

Comment: The python docs for 3.6 say that it doesnt support empty split https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.split. is says: "Patterns that can only match empty strings currently never split the string. Since this doesn’t match the expected behavior, a ValueError will be raised starting from Python 3.5"

Comment: However 3.7 documentation says: Changed in version 3.7: Added support of splitting on a pattern that could match an empty string. So i guess it will really dpeend on your version. empty split worked in 3.5 and gave warning, stopped in 3.6 and seems to work again in 3.7 from what i understand from the python docs.

Answer (score 4):

Try `str.split('(#[a-z]+)', expand=True)`

**Ex:**

```
serie = pd.Series(['this#is#a#test', 'another#test'])
print(serie.str.split('(#[a-z]+)', expand=True)
```

Comment: Out of my curiosity, why is there columns 2, 4 and 6 with no data ?

Answer (score 0):

Just simply add it at each line:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: serie = pd.Series(['this#is#a#test', 'another#test'])

In [3]: serie.str.split('#', expand=True) + '#'
Out[3]:
          0      1    2      3
0     this#    is#   a#  test#
1  another#  test#  NaN    NaN

In [4]: '#' + serie.str.split('#', expand=True)
Out[4]:
          0      1    2      3
0     #this    #is   #a  #test
1  #another  #test  NaN    NaN
```

Comment: Yes, thank you... I added and edit about intended use case with regex matching, so the string to keep can be dynamic.

Comment: There is no `#` in column 0 in OP's desired output or the data itself.